# Doorkeeper with MFA support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I am using Doorkeeper OAuth 2 for Rails and would like to add MFA support. For example, to be able to additionally ask users to confirm their login via Google Authenticator or, for example, via SMS. I can't find such a feature in the Doorkeeper documentation. Is it possible to implement MFA with Doorkeeper?

Comment: Found this; but I, myself, haven't used this for Google authenticator or anyhting, but have used the one time password in a previous company. https://coderwall.com/p/qw7hwq/effortless-two-factor-authentication-in-rails

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks like this extension is just additional layer which should be introduced right after successful DoorKeeper authentication process? It is not a part of DoorKeeper? So in case I have implemented SSO over DoorKeeper OpenID Connect and connected for example 3rd party web app to DoorKeeper written in Python - I have to add another MFA layer directly into the Python app after authentication with DoorKeeper and redirection back to the Python web app?

Comment: Ya I'm not 100%. I do know that Auth0 supports MFA and SSO logins. Not sure if that's something feasible for your use case tho. But just an idea :D